# Increase button font size when button size is changing

Tags: qt, resize, fullscreen

I'm having a Qt application with a main window that has five buttons aligned in a vertical order.
They all have the same size.

All I want to do is to increase the font size of the button label when the app goes fullscreen.
I would really appreciate a solution that does not need too much code ... was hoping that this was something that could be done in Qt Designer, but I couldn't find a way how to.

Any suggestions?

Best,

guitarflow

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I can't think of any way to do it in designer, but it's really not too much code. Here's a quick-and-dirty proof of concept. You'd want to take into account margins (using `QStyle::pixelMetrics` and the like), but you get the idea.

```
#include <QtGui>

class FontAdjustingButton : public QPushButton {
public:
  explicit FontAdjustingButton(QWidget *parent = NULL) : QPushButton(parent) {
    setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::Expanding, QSizePolicy::Expanding);
  }
protected:
  void resizeEvent(QResizeEvent *event) {
    int button_margin = style()->pixelMetric(QStyle::PM_ButtonMargin);
    QFont f = font();
    f.setPixelSize(event->size().height() - button_margin * 2);
    setFont(f);
  }
};

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  QApplication app(argc, argv);
  QWidget w;
  QVBoxLayout *layout = new QVBoxLayout;
  for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
    FontAdjustingButton *btn = new FontAdjustingButton;
    btn->setText(QString("Hello, world %1").arg(i));
    layout->addWidget(btn);
  }
  w.setLayout(layout);
  w.show();
  return app.exec();
}
```

Comment: Ok, I got that. Works great!! If not been into this whole layouting stuff before, so could you please tell me what you mean by QStyle::pixelMetrics? Interesting to delve into this a bit more.

Comment: I edited the code to consider the button margin. The QStyle class lets you get hints on what looks "right" for each platform. You generally use its methods to help you draw GUI elements. (http://doc.qt.nokia.com/stable/qstyle.html)

Comment: Thank you very much! Looks good! Would like to give you an upvote, but unfortunately I don't have enough reputation to do so!! Will do it as soon as I may. Best regards!!

Comment: Can I somehow see how wide the label text actually is? I would need the button labels to be perfectly aligned and I would like to use the width of the widest label text to calculate how much left-padding I have to use for all five buttons. Thanks again!

Comment: Actually, if you don't mind, post this as a separate question. That will (a) make it more visible so that you get more answers, and (b) make it more easily discoverable in case someone else has the some question later.

Comment: I would do that but I found a solution myself in the meantime. Found another question here on SO which deals with that exact problem, so it would not be necessary ( and even be against the board rules ) to ask the same question again. Nevertheless, thanks for your help.