# Qt radio button switch display delay

Tags: qt, user-interface, radio-button, event-loop

I'm having a Qt application here where I have a main window with 5 QPushButtons that are aligned vertically.
These buttons work in a radio-group manner.
This means, that they are checkable and auto-exclusive.
Since I need to be able to resize the font size of the button text when the main window resizes, I included my own override of QPushButton and set it as custom widget in designer.

What I don't understand is, that there is a heavy delay when I switch from one button to another via keyboard shortcuts! Same when I click with the mouse.
I would say that this delay is about 0.5 to 1 second.
Have tried it on different machines.

I really need to get rid of this!

Anyone has an idea of what I could do to fix this??

Edit : Just found out that this behavior is the same when I just use normal QPushButtons. It seems that the delay is getting more when the buttons are getting bigger. Any help is strongly appreciated!!!

Comment: What does your custom QPushButton class do? Mind to share some code?

Comment: It increases the button font size proportional to its size. [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8052201/increase-button-font-size-when-button-size-is-changing). I actually implemented it as @Dave mentioned it. I only included some more things that the text on the button is always centered. But I guess this would be a little bit out of context if I post it.

Comment: Put a `qDebug() << Q_FUNC_INFO` statement at the start of each of the methods you *have* overwritten in your custom QPushButton class. Make sure those are not being called bazillions of times. If not, the problem must be elsewhere. If you change them to regular QPushButtons, do you still have the problem? It is *only* with keyboard shortcuts, or if you click with the mouse also?

Comment: So the text on the button with the longest text is centered, and then the other buttons are left-aligned based on that button?

Comment: Just did that debugging thing. The `resizeEvent` function is executed 5 times ( once for each button ). When switching through the buttons, just the `paintEvent(QPaintEvent*)` function is called. Don't know why, but it is called 6 times on every button change.

Comment: @Dave : Yeah, exactly. I'm not 100% lucky with this, but hey, time is money ;-)

Answer (score 0):

A shot in the dark: Setting the font might cause another resizeEvent, which in turn causes another one and so on... Try putting the font adjustment code into a method that you explicitly call when you enter/leave full screen mode.

Comment: Thanks for the idea, but I already tried that. The resiveEvent is called 5 times and it is just called when the main window size changes